# What's the workflow for determining if a bug is the browser's fault, or my own?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser, pixi.js

I'm working on a project right now and I've written some code using Pixi.js that produces strange results in Google Chrome. Specifically, drawing a sprite with a texture seems to be creating a strange issue where multiple loaded textures are drawn on top of each other, when only one was requested. (e.g. I say "load a cat, load a dog, draw a cat" and for some reason I see a cat on top of a dog.)

I don't see this issue in Firefox or in Safari. I'm not sure if this is my own bug, a bug in Pixi.js, or a bug in the browser. It doesn't really matter, because that's not really what this question is about-- I'm just telling this story for context.

**My question is: what is the general workflow for determining whether or not a bug is my own, or a problem with the browser?** Is there some standard process for debugging browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a standard process, but from my experience with PIXI, I've found that when the bug is in my code it generally shows up in all the browsers.

Browsers often have differences in HTML/CSS, but they seem to display the canvas the same. So if the issue is with the general layout of the entire canvas or other DOM elements, I would assume it's a browser issue.

But if the problem is with rendering a PIXI component on the stage, it is more likely either a PIXI bug or a bug in your code. Keep in mind PIXIjs renders using WebGL if available, otherwise it falls back on the HTML5 canvas. So I would check that first by turning WebGL on and off within the same browser and see if it makes a difference.

If you're curious to know why your dog didn't render correctly, go ahead and post some code :)